# Name of this fractal

Tags: fractals

I am writing my final paper in the field ob computer enginering my work are on fractals. Some time ago, I found this fractal. Now I need to refer to it in my work but i have no clue what is it called. I searched the internet but found nothing really useful. The only mention fractal that I found is called an outward circle but its not exactly the same. http://pixgood.com/fractal-circle.html! My fractal :[image]

Comment: WHat's not exactly the same about it?  They look nearly identical, except you've drawn yours with solid circles instead of hollow ones.

Comment: True i forgot that the circles cross each other. It the name ok thou ?

Comment: Google Image search found this: http://grafika.me/node/206

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got a slight variation of a standard visualization of the Cayley graph of the free group on two generators.  If you take a look at the [Wikipedia page on Cayley graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph), one of the first images you see is something like so:

[image]

Now, if we just place disks at the vertices scaled appropriately, we pretty much generate your image:

[image]

Of course, it's fractal properties will depend on the choice of scaling factor between steps.  It think I've chosen a somewhat smaller scaling factor than you to generate my image.

Answer (score 1):

Fractal Kvaziklever according to http://grafika.me/node/206

Comment: That's pseudo-clover in Russian, right? So the name is definitely wrong $-$ the fractal in the picture is missing the bottom quadrant (because it's a clover-leaf).

Comment: Close but not quiet the same.