# Solve $\sum \phi(q) q^{- 2 s} = 1$ for $s$ with rigourous error bounds

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, fractals

I'm trying to solve for $s$ the summation:

$$\sum_{q=2}^\infty \phi(q) \left(\frac{1}{q^2}\right)^s = 1$$

where $\phi(q)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

The context is trying to calculate the fractal similarity dimension of [a synthetic model of recursive ever-smaller kissing circles similar in appearance to parts of the Mandelbrot set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1141142).

I have written fairly naive C++ code to bisect $s$ between $0$ and $2$ in double precision, evaluating the left hand side using double precision for each term and accumulating them with higher precision types like double-double and quad-double unevaluated sums (using `libqd`).

I'm repeatedly doubling the number of terms to see how it behaves, it seems to be slowly increasing, converging to around $s \approx 1.24$ but how can I be sure that it won't increase all the way to $2$, or eventually decrease again, or that rounding errors aren't destroying all hope of an accurate result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}$ from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Examples), thus you're solving $\zeta(2s-1)=2\zeta(2s)$. With [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), one finds $$s=1.2393753928669801303357436306951677\ldots$$ by issuing `solve(s=1.2,1.3,zeta(2*s-1)-2*zeta(2*s))`. This is the only solution, since $$\frac{d}{ds}\big(\zeta(2s-1)-2\zeta(2s)\big)=-2\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{(n-2)\log n}{n^{2s}}<0.$$